# just able to add dom elements but not remove them

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, google-chrome

i am not able to remove elements from the dom. i am using firfox. my code looks like this

i have a form for which all text boxes should be filled before submission. my form looks like this

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="url" onsubmit="return checkEmpty(this)" >
<div class="field">
<label>field1</label><input type="text" name="f1" />
</div>
<div class="field">
<label>field2</label><input type="text" name="f2" />
</div>
..
....
......
input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

what i do here is that when a form is submitted i check if any text box is empty and if there is any i create a dom element h3 and append it to the div of that corresponding field and if the text box is not empty i check if there is any text box attached to that corresponding field and if i find one i remove it. here is my javascript code

```
function checkEmpty(form) {
   var textboxes=form.elements;
   for(var i=0;i<textboxes.length;i++)
   {
      if((textboxes[i].type=="text" || textboxes[i].type=="password") && textboxes[i].textLength==0)                  //text box is empty,this code works in firefox but not in chrome                     
      {
         var msg=document.createElement('h3');
         msg.innerHTML="u cant leave this field blank";
         textboxes[i].parentNode.appendChild(msg);
         return false;
      }
      else                      //text box is not empty,this code neither works in firefox nor in chrome 
      {
         var rem_msg=textboxes[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName('h3');
         for(var j=0;j<rem_msg.length;j++)
            textboxes[i].parentNode.removeChild(rem_msg[j]);
      }
   }
}
```

Until i was not removing elements the code was working fine but removing element is neccessary because for example a user doesnt enter any value in text box 1 on first attempt so an h3 element would be added but now he enters some text in first text box but leaves second text box empty so the h3 element of first text box should dissappear.
 the code looks really simple, i am getting the reference of a node and then passing in to `appendChild` or `removeChild`. Also i am not even able to add elements to the dom in google chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change the line that creates the error to `if ((textboxes[i].type == "text" || textboxes[i].type == "password") && textboxes[i].value == "")`  possible will work

Comment: if i remove the `else` block the code works fine i mean i m able to add elements but only in firefox.in chrome even if all the text boxes are empty and i click submit the form is submitted

Comment: can i mark 2 answers as accepted bcoz u solved one part of my question and the other answer solved next part. i have upvoted ur answer

Comment: @lovesh no. You can upvote both but you can accept as solution only one

Comment: can u please look at the other answer and tell me why my code didnt work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
 rem_msg[j].parentNode.removeChild(rem_msg[j]);
```

Comment: also it doesnt work in chrome. even if all the text boxes are empty and i click submit the form is submitted

Comment: can i mark 2 answers as accepted bcoz u solved one part of my question and the other answer solved next part. i have upvoted ur answer